# Загрузка Kubuntu 11.10 в текстовом режиме

Tags: boot, kubuntu

Подскажите плиз, где подпилить, при загрузке в текстовом режиме, когда виден весь процесс загрузки, выводимые строки текста "съезжают". Скрин там не сделать, сфотографировать не получилось, но выдаёт что-то типа этого:

```
* bla-bla-bla                * blo-blo-blo
```

Как бы их подровнять?

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке нажать `ctrl+shift+F1` появится tty1

Answer (score 1):

Это бывает когда установлены неверные режимы консоли, нужно где-то поставить stty onlcr